# Right way to instantiate GameObject?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, instantiation, gameobject

So I have a dilemma about right way to instantiate prefab gameObject in Unity c#.

Here is the 2 example codes

Example 1:

```
public Transform musicPrefab;
GameObject mManager = (GameObject)Instantiate(musicPrefab,transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
```

Example 2:

```
public Transform musicPrefab;
Object mManager = Instantiate(musicPrefab,transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
```

But instantiating as Object works as well, ***so which way is right way?***

Comment: GameObject should have its specific methods which are not available in Object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type `object` is way too general. It doesn't really make much sense, because you won't be able to do anything meaningful with `object` inside Unity3D. When you instantiate a prefab, you usually expect to create a `GameObject` (is there a situation when you actually don't get a GameObject?? I've personally never encountered such scenario...), so that should be the right way. GameObject has many properties and methods you can utilize. You would have to cast the result to GameObject in some later point either way...

Comment: That explains it, so I should always go for GameObject when instantiating because of properties. Got it now, so object is kinda "useless".

Comment: You don't always need to instantiate as a GameObject... Say you have an "Item" class that has specific methods that you want to access. You can do Item item = Instantiate(itemPrefab, positionOfItem, rotationOfItem) as Item; that way you don't have to use the GetComponent() method when trying to access the item script on your gameObject